# Get dom elements characteristic after ajax sucess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I get video duration thanks to video.duration after my ajax video upload.
After ajax sucess, this function keeps on returning NaN.

Already tried to do things like $.when().then or $.when.done().

```
//Ajax call there

success: function(data){
   var video=$(".uploadVideoContainer[data-upload='"+id+"'] video")[0];

   $(".videoSource[data-upload='"+id+"']").attr('src', data.src);

},
complete: function(){

   $.when(video.load()).done(function(){

     console.log(video.duration);

     duration=duration*1000;
     $("input[name='EndTime["+id+"]']").val(duration);
   });


}
```

Answer might be very simple but i've been spending too much time on this to be able to see my dummy mistake.
Many thanks !

**EDIT** Forgot to declare video in the complete callback but it is still returning the same result after having declared it

Comment: You declare `var video` in the success callback, it's not available in the complete callback.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my post to declare it in the complete callback

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try doing the below

```js
var interval = window.setInterval(function(t){
  if (video.readyState > 0) {
    var duration = Math.round(video.duration) * 1000;
    $("input[name='EndTime[" + id + "]']").val(duration);
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
},500);
```

Comment: works fine with round(video.duration) instead of round(duration) (otherwise it is not declared) and clearinterval should not receive t but the interval itself as an argument.

Comment: yes it does ! Might the more efficient way to go but it does thanks !